# Unable to fetch the text from the grid in robot framework and selenium

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework, selenium2library, automation-testing

I am using Python-Robot framework-Selenium Library2. One grid is under testing. I want to fetch the value/text from first row of the grid and save to one variable. Text is something like 'MM'. I have tried with all the xpaths. From robot framework I have used Get Text, Get Value, Get Element Attribute and all possible functions from selenium 2 library but it is not working.

Couple of examples of my tries;

1. `${Code} =  Get Text   xpath=//*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr[${rows}]/td[22]`
2. `${Code} =  Get Text //tr[@id='1b2-455']//td[contains(text(),'MM')]`
3. `${code} =   Get Element Attribute    xpath=//*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr[${rows}]/td[22]    value`

Any suggestion? Thanks !